# coding convention for UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

My question is very simple, I just want to understand why some people using `extension` for those delegate methods of `UITableViewController`? Why not directly code inside the controller? What I mean is, I saw people doing this:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
   // bla bla

}

extension MyTableViewController {
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   }
   ...
}
```

What is the benefit of having the delegate methods implementation in extension? Why not just put the code inside MyTableViewController without extension? If it is a convention, then, why? What is good to do so & what is bad not doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today Maintainable of our code is more important than Performance

With this in mind, more programmers search to accomplish this task with extravagant stratagems. Using extension is one of them.

With an extensions you could make your code more readable.

But this trick is really helpful?

**Single responsibility principle** affirm that an object should be responsible of a single task.

In our ViewControllers we usually put so many things like TableView, IBAction, CollectionView and so on...

So, how can I follow the SRP without using the extension?

Just create a new object which will be delegate to manage, for example, the TableView.

```
class TableController: NSObject {
    var dataSource: [Any]

    init(dataSource: [Any]) {
        super.init()
        self.dataSource = dataSource
    }

}

// here extension could help you to make your code more readable
extension TableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    /* the TableViewDataSource method */
}
```

So, now, in your ViewController you can do this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView! 

    var tableController: TableController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableController = TableController.init(dataSource: [1,2,3])
        self.tableView.dataSource = self.tableController
   }

}
```

Hope this help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController generally contains many functions like `IBOutlets, Private helper functions, IBActions and ViewController LifeCycle` methods etc. If you put all your code in ViewController it becomes little difficult to read and hard to maintain as we add more functionality. Extensions is one of the ways to separate the logical functionality in separate files so that it's easy to read and maintain the code and modify when needed. Using extension to put all the functions which confirms to some protocol like UITableViewDataSource is one way.

One benefit of using extension is that you create multiple files and add the functions like in normal classes.

Disadvantage is you can't access private variables from the classes also can't declare constants in extensions.

If you prefer to keep the code in same file then using `//MARK:` is another way to group similar functionalities

```
//MARK: ViewController LifeCycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
}
```